# retrieving 2 arrays from php to ajax

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve two arrays from PHP using AJAX, but I thought that `json_encode` can only have one variable. Do you have any idea how I can solve this? I'm a newbie using `json_encode`

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_grades_boy)){

                $data_grades_boys[]=array(
                    'fname_b'=>$row['firstname'],
                    'mname_b' => $row['middlename'],
                    'lname_b' => $row['lastname'],
                    'studnt_id_b' => $row['student_id'],
                    'grade_b' => $row['grade'],
                    ); 
             }

             while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_grades_girl)){

                $data_grades_girls[]=array(
                    'fname_g'=>$row2['firstname'],
                    'mname_g' => $row2['middlename'],
                    'lname_g' => $row2['lastname'],
                    'studnt_id_g' => $row2['student_id'],
                    'grade_g' => $row2['grade'],
                    ); 
             }
echo json_encode($data_grades_boys);
```

I tried doing this

```
  echo json_encode($data_grades_boys);
echo json_encode($data_grades_girls);
```

to retrieve but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the both arrays into a single array:

```
$data_grades = array(
    'boys'  => $data_grades_boys,
    'girls' => $data_grades_girls
);
echo json_encode($data_grades);
```

and jquery:

```
$ajax(
...
success: function(data) {
    boys = data.boys;
    girls = data.girls
```

then

```
$.each(boys).function(index, value) {
```

Comment: it doesnt work dude. ill be retrieving it with ajax using $.each

Comment: are you getting any errors? please see the js code I've just added to the answer

Comment: sorry i didnt reload. yeah it worked!! thanks.. now i cant sleep.. thanks a lot dude. you gave me a sleep.